# Elasticsearch partial match for dirty data

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a fulltext search on a string that may not be correct yet.

Something with the data that resmeble  this

```
 {"content":"sdesteTcnnomavedadmconformWo Tech ltdaassas"}
```

I want to be able to search it for ltda and i am doing this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http:/localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/MY_TYPE/_search' -d '{"query":{"wildcard":{"content":"*LTDA*"}}}'
```

I created the content field as a not_analyzed:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/MY_INDEX' -d '{"MY_TYPE":{"properties":{"content":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}'
```

And i am still unable to do a partial match, should I change something on the index itself?

PS: I know elasticsearch would not do great with a dirty content but the idea is that the content will be cleaned and searchable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try regexp search

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/MY_TYPE/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "content": ".*ltda.*"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Yes, that did it . Thanks